# Dynamic select box not populating TypeAhead input text correctly after Jquery onchange

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, typeahead

I'm using [Twitter TypeAhead plugin](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) on my project and i would like to modify my script to populate input text correctly. I found similar questions about but unfortunatly i didn't get the correct way to solve this:

1. [Dynamically populating Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829574/dynamically-populating-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead)
2. [populate select box based on the another select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218803/populate-select-box-based-on-the-another-select-box)
3. [populate select box on selecting another selectbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470780/populate-select-box-on-selecting-another-selectbox)

Based on description above and for reference, i created a html page that display my doubt: http://testsitex2019.000webhostapp.com/

First, i will show MySql table that call (**products**) where contains records that are populated into input text:

```
id | categoryFK (Foreing Key) | ProductName   | image
--------------------------------------------------------
01 | 1 (Shoes)                | Adidas Shoes  | img_01
02 | 1 (Shoes)                | Nike Shoes    | img_02
03 | 1 (Shoes)                | Red Tenis     | img_03
04 | 2 (Clothes)              | Black Jacket  | img_04
05 | 2 (Clothes)              | Blu T-shirt   | img_05
```

Now i will show the html code that display:

1. A select box that are populated with php code (**#category**);
2. An input text that are populated with TypeAhead plugin (**#products**);
3. And a div (**#image**) that display a value when user select an option into input text (**#products**).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- CSS library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="max-width:1230px;">
<h1>DYNAMIC BOOTSTRAP TWITTER TYPEAHEAD</h1>
<hr>
<br>
<div class="row">

<?php 
    // Include the database config file 
    include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 

    // Fetch all the category data 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category ASC"; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 
?>

<!-- category dropdown -->
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Categories</label>
<select id="categoryFK" name="categoryFK" class="form-control">
    <option value="">select category</option>
    <?php 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['categoryID'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Category not available</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<label>Product name</label>
<input type="text" name="products" id="products" class="form-control input-lg typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select category and then type product name here" />

</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<label>(<i>The image name will be display here after select TypeAhead value</i>)</label>
<div id="image" class="image" name="image" height="15px" style="background-color:#f2f0f0;"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Below are the TypeAhead and Ajax script where Ajax script send request to php script, receive response and send data to TypeAhead populate input text:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var products;
var names = []; // array
var list = {}; // object

$('#categoryFK').on('change', function(){

var queryID = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",

    data:{category:queryID},
    dataType:"json",
success:function(data){
console.log(data);

$.each(data, function(i, optionHtml){
              $('#products').append(optionHtml);
           });

$(".typeahead").val ('');
$( ".image" ).empty();
products = data;

 }
 });

 $('.typeahead').typeahead({

  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.each(products, function(idx, item){

      if(!~names.indexOf(item.productName)) names.push(item.productName);
      list[item.productName] = item.image;
   });
   return result(names);
},
  afterSelect: function (data) {
  var tmp = list[data];

   $('#image').html(tmp);

},

 });

}); 
});
</script>
```

And finally, the php script (**fetch.php**) that receive Ajax request and send results in JSON:

```php
<?php
require_once 'dbConfig.php';

if(isset($_POST["category"])){
    $request = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["category"]);

    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM products WHERE categoryFK = ".$request."
    ";

    $result = $db->query($query);
    $data = array ();

    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 )
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc ())
        {
            $data[] = $row;

        }

 header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
 echo json_encode($data);
 exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Doubt: When user select category select box (**#category**), the TypeAhead input text (**#products**) is populated with records related with selected category ID.

When this happen for the first time, the input text is populated correctly, but when user select category value into select box (**#category**) without refreshing page, the Typeahead input text (**#products**) is populated with all records from products table instead of populate just records that are related with selected category ID.

In this [page that i created](http://testsitex2019.000webhostapp.com/), you can see how all code above works, but i didn't get a correct way to modify the scripts to populate TypeAhead input text correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some adjustments, i managed to find a solution. I kept the variable "list" and made an adjustment in the afterSelect event of Typeahead where after selecting an option inside input text **#products** the afterSelect event sends a value related with the selected item to div **#image**. This solution can be seen works [here](http://testsitex2019.000webhostapp.com/).

Below, the Ajax and TypeAhead script were adjusted and now works as well. The adjustment was made in Ajax success and TypeAhead afterSelect event:

```
        var products;
        var list = {}; // object

        $ ( function ()
        {
            $('#categoryFK').on('change', function(){
                var queryID = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:"fetch.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data: {
                        category: queryID
                    },
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
/* The adjust was made here on Ajax success */

                        console.log(data);
                        
                        $("#products").val ('');
                        
                        products = data;
                        
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#products').typeahead({
                source: function ( query, result )
                {
                    result ( $.map(products, function (item)
                        {
                            return item.productName;
                            
                        }
                    ));
                    
                },
            
                /* The adjust was made here on afterSelect event */
                
                  afterSelect: function(data) {
       $.each(products, function(idx, item){
   
      list[item.productName] = item.image;
   });
  
   
   var img = list[data];
  
   $('#image').html(img);
   
   
  },                        
            });
            
        });
```

Finally, that was the solution that i found to my doubt. If someone suggests some optimization in the code above, it will be nice. Thanks.